# How do I insert a new node into a series of xml docs (varchar column type) in sql server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I've got a few thousand rows stored as xml in a varchar column, and I need to add a new node to each of them. I've read that there is no update mechanism and pretty much the only way I can do this is to read out the rows, update them locally, then write them back in.

If this were a small number of rows I'd do it manually, but I can't go through several thousand of them or my brain will melt (I don't want that).

Are there any external tools that could help or even just good techniques for doing updates of this kind/volume?

I'm not 100% sure if we've got an xsd defined but I imagine we do (I can create one, in any case).

**Clarification:** I did not design the table and it's unlikely I'll be able to change it to an actual xml type column

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of the XML before and after the update? It might be possible to do something using *charindex* and *stuff*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

- add a new column of type `XML` to your table

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD XmlColumn XML
  ```
- fill that column with the values from that other column

  ```
  UPDATE dbo.YourTable
  SET XmlColumn = CAST(YourVarcharColumn AS XML)
  ```
- in your XML column, add that tag you need

  ```
  UPDATE dbo.YourTable
  SET XmlColumn.modify(.....)
  ```
- if you really need it, update the `varchar` column from the XML column again (but **WHY** is it `varchar` in the first place, when it really contains XML????)

  ```
  UPDATE dbo.YourTable
  SET YourVarcharColumn = CAST(XmlColumn AS VARCHAR(xx))
  ```

Comment: Don't ask me, I didn't design the table! Should have clarified that in the first place - it's unlikely I'll be allowed to edit the structure.

Comment: @Alex: could you define a temporary table with some kind of a primary key for each row, and the `varchar` and a new `XML` column??

Comment: Temp table would be a way to go I suppose. Can I do use bulk ops for updating/re-inserting the xml? I'll be adding the exact same node to all the rows, so I won't have to worry about different parameters or anything

Comment: @Alex : you could probably just run a single UPDATE statement over your temp table if the XML structure is similar enough between all rows, and the XML you're inserting is the same for each row